# Jquery loop and strange behavior of variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm sorry, but I can't find better title for my question, but I'll try to better describe my problem.
I have this code:

```
let pdfInvoice_sub_template = [
        {text: '{i}', alignment: 'center'},
        {text: 'invoices_sub-{i}-name', alignment: 'left'},
        {text: 'invoices_sub-{i}-unit', alignment: 'center'},
    ];
temp_pdfSubTemplate = [];

for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        temp_pdfSubTemplate[i] = pdfInvoice_sub_template;
        jQuery.each(temp_pdfSubTemplate[i], function (key, val) {
                 document.write(val.text = val.text.replace(/{i}/g, i) + '</br>');
        });
}
```

And hoping add two elements to the object, like this:

```
  temp_pdfSubTemplate [[{ text: '1', alignment: 'center' },{ text: 'invoices_sub-1-name', alignment: 'left' },{ text: 'invoices_sub-1-unit', alignment: 'center' }], [{ text: '2', alignment: 'center' },{ text: 'invoices_sub-2-name', alignment: 'left' },{ text: 'invoices_sub-2-unit', alignment: 'center' }]]
```

But after run this code, I have:

```
1
invoices_sub-1-name
invoices_sub-1-unit

1
invoices_sub-1-name
invoices_sub-1-unit
```

In debug devtools I see after first iterate that **pdfInvoice_sub_template** have a replaced {i} with 1, but I do replace {i} in **temp_pdfSubTemplate**. Why is happened this way and what i must to do?
Thanks!

Here is fiddler:
https://jsfiddle.net/xf4j1qpu/1/

---

Thanks to @Lennholm, who suggested the correct answer (see below), the problem was solved.
The main reason is that when I declaring **temp_pdfSubTemplate[i]** in a loop, I do not create a new object, but refer to the original object **pdfInvoice_sub_template**, and as a result, manipulations in the loop are performed on the original object.
The problem has two solutions.
In addition, as suggested by @Lennholm, instead of declaring a variable with the original object, create a function whose only task is to create the object I need(see example in @Lennholm answear). Thus, when creating a variable in a loop, it will not just be a reference to the original object, but a new one will be created.

As a second solution is to move the declarations of the original object to the beginning of the loop. Thus, the desired result is also achieved. In each new loop, a new object will be created:

```
temp_pdfSubTemplate = [];

for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
let pdfInvoice_sub_template = [
        {text: '{i}', alignment: 'center'},
        {text: 'invoices_sub-{i}-name', alignment: 'left'},
        {text: 'invoices_sub-{i}-unit', alignment: 'center'},
    ];
        temp_pdfSubTemplate[i] = pdfInvoice_sub_template;
        jQuery.each(temp_pdfSubTemplate[i], function (key, val) {
                 document.write(val.text = val.text.replace(/{i}/g, i) + '</br>');
        });
}
```

Comment: Remove `val.text = ` - you're overriding the original value with the placeholder.

Comment: Thank you. But I did overriding in **temp_pdfSubTemplate**, why is overrided in **pdfInvoice_sub_template**?? Аnd I need to get not just converted strings, but **create object elements** with values in which {i} are replaced by iteration index. But if I try to do according to your advice, I have correct strings, but then the contents of the objects remain unchanged.... Look in console https://jsfiddle.net/xf4j1qpu/2/   So... I`m steel confused..

Answer (score 2):

`pdfInvoice_sub_template` and `temp_pdfSubTemplate[i]` point to the same array. When you run `temp_pdfSubTemplate[i] = pdfInvoice_sub_template` you're only copying the *reference* to the original array, you're not creating a copy of the array itself.
That means that whenever you change something in `temp_pdfSubTemplate[i]`, that change will appear in `pdfInvoice_sub_template` as well since they are the same thing.

Hence, when you do `val.text = ...` you're overwriting the `text` property in the original template. In the next iteration, it will have `1` instead of `{i}` so the replacement fails and `1` remains.

Since you want `temp_pdfSubTemplate[i]` to be a new, unique array based on the template, my suggestion is that you make a factory function that creates this for you instead of having a predefined object.
Change your code like this:

```js
function createPdfInvoice_sub_template() {
      return [
        {text: '{i}', alignment: 'center'},
        {text: 'invoices_sub-{i}-name', alignment: 'left'},
        {text: 'invoices_sub-{i}-unit', alignment: 'center'},
      ];
    }

    temp_pdfSubTemplate = [];

    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        temp_pdfSubTemplate[i] = createPdfInvoice_sub_template();
        jQuery.each(temp_pdfSubTemplate[i], function (key, val) {
                 document.write(val.text = val.text.replace(/{i}/g, i) + '</br>');
        });
     }
     console.log(temp_pdfSubTemplate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ohhh!!! you save my life! Thank you vary much! At this moment I understand something about this..... and place the **let pdfInvoice_sub_template** at start, inside *for loop*. This too helped me (by the way, this can probably be added to the answer) but I still did not fully understand the reasons for this behavior. Now, thanks to you, everything is clear!!